# Accurate sleep duration AutoIt

Tags: sleep, autoit

I'm using an AutoIt program to manage the placement of a few windows at the moment, and I need to implement a way to cycle between activated windows at specific time intervals (on the order of every ~2 seconds).

This needs to be fairly regular, though extraordinary precision is not necessary. My initial concern is that if I just implement a simple sleep command in my main GUI's while loop, it might not be regular - for instance, if another action is executed at any point while the timer is going, it will delay the time until the sleep command is run again.

I looked through SO and the AutoIt forums and didn't see any simple way to address this. I think using a run command to launch a separate AutoIt program to do the timing would work reasonably well (in a messier way than I would prefer) because it would spawn a new process, but again, this is a messier solution than I would prefer.

Does anybody know of a better way to do this? Even a way to spawn a new process or thread within the same AutoIt program would be wonderful. Thanks

Comment: What about this? _Timer_SetTimer New process is also possible. You can start x scripts in parallel aswell. Many roads lead to rome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, have a look at _Timer_SetTimer in the helpfile.

For creating a second process have a look here:

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/103630-time-control/